# Regex replace within list inside a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, python-re

Hello I have  dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2  COL3 
G1   1     [[(OK2_+__HELLO,OJ_+__BY),(LO_-__HOLLA,KUOJ_+__BY)]]
G1   2     [[(JU3_+__BO,UJ3_-__GET)]]
```

how can I use `re.sub(r'.*__', '')` within the `COL3` sulist ?

and get a new column without evrything before '**`__`**':

```
    COL1 COL2  COL3 COL4 
    G1   1     [[(OK2_+__HELLO,OJ_+__BY),(LO_-__HOLLA,KUOJ_+__BY)]] [[(HELLO,OBY),(HOLLA,BY)]]
    G1   2     [[(JU3_+__BO,UJ3_-__GET)]] [(BO,GET)]]
```

here is the data :

```
data= {'COL1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1'}, 'COL2': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'COL3 ': {0: "[[(OK2_+__HELLO,OJ_+__BY),(LO_-__HOLLA,KUOJ_+__BY)]]", 1: "[[(JU3_+__BO,UJ3_-__GET)]]"}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Use the `replace` instead. [Doc replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: yes but the trikky thing here is that usually we use re.sub for list and replace for dataframe, but here I have both ...

Comment: Couldn't you use `str(list)`?

Comment: if I do that it treat each element within the list .. ex O, K, 2,_ etc

Comment: The content of your column COL3 seems strange. Are these strings or nested lists? can you even have nested lists in the cell of a dataframe?

Comment: @Moritz nested lists

Comment: I edidted the post with the data

Comment: Try `df['COL3'].str.replace(r"([,(]')[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*__", r'\1')`

Comment: Note you provided sample data where the `COL3` has a trailing space. Then you need `df['COL3 '].str.replace(r"([,(]')[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*__", r'\1')`

Comment: mh.. the fact that you are working with multiple tuples within nested lists makes this quite complicated and you probably have to loop through the different levels to get to the individual strings. I suppose you cannot do the processing before putting the data in this kind of nested cells?

Comment: I'm confused, you say that it's nested lists, but in the data you just posted it's actually a long string and not a nested list. "[[('OK2_+__HELLO','OJ_+__BY'),('LO_-__HOLLA','KUOJ_+__BY')]]"

Answer (score 1):

**Updated data solution**

```py
data= {'COL1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1'}, 'COL2': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'COL3 ': {0: "[[(OK2_+__HELLO,OJ_+__BY),(LO_-__HOLLA,KUOJ_+__BY)]]", 1: "[[(JU3_+__BO,UJ3_-__GET)]]"}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['COL4'] = df['COL3 '].str.replace(r"([,(])[^(),]*__", r"\1")
df['COL4']
# => 0    [[(HELLO,BY),(HOLLA,BY)]]
#    1                 [[(BO,GET)]]
#    Name: COL4, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfUkbP/1).

**Old data solution**

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn the strings in the `COL3` column into lists of lists and iterate over them while modifying the tuple items:

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd
data= {'COL1': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1'}, 'COL2': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'COL3 ': {0: "[[('OK2_+__HELLO','OJ_+__BY'),('LO_-__HOLLA','KUOJ_+__BY')]]", 1: "[[('JU3_+__BO','UJ3_-__GET')]]"}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

def repl(m):
    result = []
    for l in ast.literal_eval(m):
        ll = []
        for x, y in l:
            ll.append(tuple([re.sub(r'.*__', '', x), re.sub(r'.*__', '', y)]))
        result.append(ll)
    return str(result)

df['COL4'] = df['COL3 '].apply(repl)
df['COL4']
# => 0    [[('HELLO', 'BY'), ('HOLLA', 'BY')]]
#    1                       [[('BO', 'GET')]]
```

You do not need to use `str(result)` if you are OK to keep the result as a list of lists.

Comment: Since here it was an exemple dataframe, when I use your script on my real dataframe I get the error message : ```ValueError: malformed node or string:[[('JZSA01004897.1_7705-8662_+__SP_1', 'NW_014463939.1_1121724-1122696_+__SP_2')]]``` do you have an idea of what is going on ?

Comment: Howw I just saw something, in my data there is not ```[[('JU3_+__BO','UJ3_-__GET')]] ```but more  ```[[(JU3_+__BO,UJ3_-__GET)]]``` maybe it is because of that ?

Comment: I updated the input data, it is because of that, can you check please ? Maybe one idea would be to first change element within each list into a string in order to get  ```('JU3_+__BO','UJ3_-__GET')```syntax ?

Comment: @Grendel `df['COL4'] = df['COL3 '].str.replace(r"([,(])[^(),]*__", r"\1")`

Comment: I only get NaN values with that last code for my real data..

Comment: @Grendel Then sorry, you should first decide what your input is. It is the first step you should always do before trying out anything.

Comment: But I did not want to add all the complicated data first, it ws in order to explain better the expected algoritm...